# How to prove this analysis problem？Thanks pretty much

Tags: analysis, inequality, partial-differential-equations

suppose $u:R^3 \rightarrow R$ satisfy that $\triangle u=0$, define $$f(r)=\frac{\displaystyle\iiint\limits_{B_r}|\nabla u|^2\,dx\,dy\,dz}{r}$$where $B_r=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2\leq r^2\}$

How to show $f(r)$ is monotone decreasing function?

Comment: Why do you delete your question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2574073/42969 and then post an identical question?

Comment: sorry for my mistakes

Answer (score 1):

[Looks like the statement is wrong; counterexamples like $u(x,y,z)=x^2-y^2$ show that $f(r)$ is actually non-decreasing.]

Define $F(r)$ as the mean of $|\nabla u|^2$ on the ball $B_r$, i.e.,
$$F(r)=\frac{3}{4\pi r^3}\displaystyle\iiint\limits_{B_r}|\nabla u|^2\,dx\,dy\,dz\geq 0$$
then $f(r) =\frac{4\pi}{3}r^2F(r)$. Since $u$ is harmonic, it is easy to prove that $|\nabla u|^2$ is subharmonic ($\Delta (|\nabla u|^2)\geq 0$). From the mean value property of subharmonic functions, $F(r)$ is non-decreasing, and hence $f(r)$ is also non-decreasing.